# MudBlazor MudExpansionPanel won't display content

Tags: mudblazor

This code works on Try MudBlazor, but not in my project.  The panel's content will not render.  no errors are displayed in the Console.

This happens on versions 6.4.1 and 6.7.0.

My project targets net6.0.

```
<MudPaper Class="pa-4 mt-4">
    <h2>Roles:</h2>
    <MudExpansionPanels Class="mt-4" MultiExpansion="true">
        <MudExpansionPanel Text="Group 1" IsInitiallyExpanded="true" DisableGutters="true">
            <MudTable Items="@Roles" MultiSelection="true" Elevation="0">
                <ColGroup>
                    <col style="width: 80px;" />
                </ColGroup>
                <RowTemplate>
                    <MudTd>@context</MudTd>
                </RowTemplate>
            </MudTable>
        </MudExpansionPanel>
        <MudExpansionPanel Text="Group 2" IsInitiallyExpanded="true" DisableGutters="true">
            <MudTable Items="@Roles" MultiSelection="true" Elevation="0">
                <ColGroup>
                    <col style="width: 80px;" />
                </ColGroup>
                <RowTemplate>
                    <MudTd>@context</MudTd>
                </RowTemplate>
            </MudTable>
        </MudExpansionPanel>
    </MudExpansionPanels>
</MudPaper>

@code {
    private IEnumerable<string> Roles = new List<string>() {
        "Owner",
        "Editor"
    };
}
```

Comment: it works in a new project from the MudBlazor template.  so obviously something else in my project... will update if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  I had unprefixed css styles for a highly customized navmenu...

```
.mud-collapse-container {
  display: none;
}
```

fixed with this:

```
.mud-navmenu .mud-collapse-container {
  display: none;
}
```